# How to rethrow a C++ exception as a .net exception preserving the message, stack trace and original exception?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a "wrapper library" in C++/CLI that talks to an unmanaged third-party library to make the functionality available in my .net projects. Some functions of the unmanaged library throw exceptions which inherit from `std::exception`. I want to re-throw them as meaningful exceptions in .net space.
Currently, I do this with every unmanaged call:

```
try {
    myThirdPartyObject -> doUnmanagedStuff();
} catch(std::exception e) {
    throw gcnew InvalidOperationException(gcnew String(e.what()));
}
```

However this does neither preserve the call stack nor the original exception. If I just let the exception bubble up, I only get it as a `SEHException` with the message "An external component has thrown an exception".

Is this possible and if yes, how is it done?

Comment: A little bit off topic, but you should catch the C++ exceptions by reference (`catch (std::exception& e)`)

Comment: Indeed, to avoid slicing. "const" reference is even better (`catch (const std::exception& e))`

Comment: @SébastienCôté: Why is catching a const reference better? You will never get a const exception in a `catch` block. And you could not call any non-const functions or modify the exception before rethrowing.

Comment: @Stephan See "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145147/why-catch-an-exception-as-reference-to-const" and "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581654/about-catching-exception-good-practices"

Comment: You don't get a stack trace or anything but exception::what() in a native C++ program either.  That does not get magically better when you rethrow it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is feasible. Unlike managed code, Standard C++ is *not* backed by a runtime engine that takes care of those things for you. There are ways to capture the stack trace, but they are platform-specific (see the Windows way [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)); and anyway, the stack information should be captured and attached to the exception object *before* throwing it, which in your case is not an option since you are calling into a third-party library I assume you cannot modify.

Comment: "sentient runtime engine"?

Comment: Pedantic expression for the CLR :)